# Cartopy examples produce a Segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7, cartopy

Cartopy can't draw virtually anything. Even [a simple example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/intro-1.py) results in a segfault. `Segmentation fault` is all Python `3.7.0` says before crashing. So does Python `3.6.6`.

The faulty line appear to be `ax.coastlines()`.

`ax.gridlines()` gives the same silent segfault as well.

`matplotlib` is `2.2.3`.

Cartopy is the most recent by the date, `0.16.0`, installed with `pip`. All the requirements (`six`, `pyshp`, `setuptools`, `shapely`, `numpy`) are met. Reinstalling with `pip` doesn't help. Installing the same Cartopy version from repo doesn't help either. The OS is Debian 10 (beta).

The same outcome is with Cartopy `0.15.1`.

What else can I check to find the cause of the segfault?

Just in case, `matplotlib.rcParams` are the following:

```
_internal.classic_mode: False
agg.path.chunksize: 0
animation.avconv_args: []
animation.avconv_path: avconv
animation.bitrate: -1
animation.codec: h264
animation.convert_args: []
animation.convert_path: convert
animation.embed_limit: 20.0
animation.ffmpeg_args: []
animation.ffmpeg_path: ffmpeg
animation.frame_format: png
animation.html: none
animation.html_args: []
animation.writer: ffmpeg
axes.autolimit_mode: data
axes.axisbelow: line
axes.edgecolor: k
axes.facecolor: w
axes.formatter.limits: [-7, 7]
axes.formatter.min_exponent: 0
axes.formatter.offset_threshold: 4
axes.formatter.use_locale: False
axes.formatter.use_mathtext: False
axes.formatter.useoffset: True
axes.grid: False
axes.grid.axis: both
axes.grid.which: major
axes.hold: None
axes.labelcolor: k
axes.labelpad: 4.0
axes.labelsize: medium
axes.labelweight: normal
axes.linewidth: 0.8
axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf'])
axes.spines.bottom: True
axes.spines.left: True
axes.spines.right: True
axes.spines.top: True
axes.titlepad: 6.0
axes.titlesize: large
axes.titleweight: normal
axes.unicode_minus: True
axes.xmargin: 0.05
axes.ymargin: 0.05
axes3d.grid: True
backend: TkAgg
backend.qt4: None
backend.qt5: None
backend_fallback: True
boxplot.bootstrap: None
boxplot.boxprops.color: k
boxplot.boxprops.linestyle: -
boxplot.boxprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.capprops.color: k
boxplot.capprops.linestyle: -
boxplot.capprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.color: k
boxplot.flierprops.linestyle: none
boxplot.flierprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.marker: o
boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor: k
boxplot.flierprops.markerfacecolor: none
boxplot.flierprops.markersize: 6.0
boxplot.meanline: False
boxplot.meanprops.color: C2
boxplot.meanprops.linestyle: --
boxplot.meanprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.meanprops.marker: ^
boxplot.meanprops.markeredgecolor: C2
boxplot.meanprops.markerfacecolor: C2
boxplot.meanprops.markersize: 6.0
boxplot.medianprops.color: C1
boxplot.medianprops.linestyle: -
boxplot.medianprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.notch: False
boxplot.patchartist: False
boxplot.showbox: True
boxplot.showcaps: True
boxplot.showfliers: True
boxplot.showmeans: False
boxplot.vertical: True
boxplot.whiskerprops.color: k
boxplot.whiskerprops.linestyle: -
boxplot.whiskerprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.whiskers: 1.5
contour.corner_mask: True
contour.negative_linestyle: dashed
datapath: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
date.autoformatter.day: %Y-%m-%d
date.autoformatter.hour: %m-%d %H
date.autoformatter.microsecond: %M:%S.%f
date.autoformatter.minute: %d %H:%M
date.autoformatter.month: %Y-%m
date.autoformatter.second: %H:%M:%S
date.autoformatter.year: %Y
docstring.hardcopy: False
errorbar.capsize: 0.0
examples.directory: 
figure.autolayout: False
figure.constrained_layout.h_pad: 0.04167
figure.constrained_layout.hspace: 0.02
figure.constrained_layout.use: False
figure.constrained_layout.w_pad: 0.04167
figure.constrained_layout.wspace: 0.02
figure.dpi: 100.0
figure.edgecolor: w
figure.facecolor: w
figure.figsize: [6.4, 4.8]
figure.frameon: True
figure.max_open_warning: 20
figure.subplot.bottom: 0.11
figure.subplot.hspace: 0.2
figure.subplot.left: 0.125
figure.subplot.right: 0.9
figure.subplot.top: 0.88
figure.subplot.wspace: 0.2
figure.titlesize: large
figure.titleweight: normal
font.cursive: ['Apple Chancery', 'Textile', 'Zapf Chancery', 'Sand', 'Script MT', 'Felipa', 'cursive']
font.family: ['sans-serif']
font.fantasy: ['Comic Sans MS', 'Chicago', 'Charcoal', 'ImpactWestern', 'Humor Sans', 'xkcd', 'fantasy']
font.monospace: ['DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Computer Modern Typewriter', 'Andale Mono', 'Nimbus Mono L', 'Courier New', 'Courier', 'Fixed', 'Terminal', 'monospace']
font.sans-serif: ['DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Computer Modern Sans Serif', 'Lucida Grande', 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Lucid', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Avant Garde', 'sans-serif']
font.serif: ['DejaVu Serif', 'Bitstream Vera Serif', 'Computer Modern Roman', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Utopia', 'ITC Bookman', 'Bookman', 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'Times New Roman', 'Times', 'Palatino', 'Charter', 'serif']
font.size: 10.0
font.stretch: normal
font.style: normal
font.variant: normal
font.weight: normal
grid.alpha: 1.0
grid.color: #b0b0b0
grid.linestyle: -
grid.linewidth: 0.8
hatch.color: k
hatch.linewidth: 1.0
hist.bins: 10
image.aspect: equal
image.cmap: viridis
image.composite_image: True
image.interpolation: nearest
image.lut: 256
image.origin: upper
image.resample: True
interactive: False
keymap.all_axes: ['a']
keymap.back: ['left', 'c', 'backspace']
keymap.forward: ['right', 'v']
keymap.fullscreen: ['f', 'ctrl+f']
keymap.grid: ['g']
keymap.grid_minor: ['G']
keymap.home: ['h', 'r', 'home']
keymap.pan: ['p']
keymap.quit: ['ctrl+w', 'cmd+w', 'q']
keymap.quit_all: ['W', 'cmd+W', 'Q']
keymap.save: ['s', 'ctrl+s']
keymap.xscale: ['k', 'L']
keymap.yscale: ['l']
keymap.zoom: ['o']
legend.borderaxespad: 0.5
legend.borderpad: 0.4
legend.columnspacing: 2.0
legend.edgecolor: 0.8
legend.facecolor: inherit
legend.fancybox: True
legend.fontsize: medium
legend.framealpha: 0.8
legend.frameon: True
legend.handleheight: 0.7
legend.handlelength: 2.0
legend.handletextpad: 0.8
legend.labelspacing: 0.5
legend.loc: best
legend.markerscale: 1.0
legend.numpoints: 1
legend.scatterpoints: 1
legend.shadow: False
lines.antialiased: True
lines.color: C0
lines.dash_capstyle: butt
lines.dash_joinstyle: round
lines.dashdot_pattern: [6.4, 1.6, 1.0, 1.6]
lines.dashed_pattern: [3.7, 1.6]
lines.dotted_pattern: [1.0, 1.65]
lines.linestyle: -
lines.linewidth: 1.5
lines.marker: None
lines.markeredgewidth: 1.0
lines.markersize: 6.0
lines.scale_dashes: True
lines.solid_capstyle: projecting
lines.solid_joinstyle: round
markers.fillstyle: full
mathtext.bf: sans:bold
mathtext.cal: cursive
mathtext.default: it
mathtext.fallback_to_cm: True
mathtext.fontset: dejavusans
mathtext.it: sans:italic
mathtext.rm: sans
mathtext.sf: sans
mathtext.tt: monospace
patch.antialiased: True
patch.edgecolor: k
patch.facecolor: C0
patch.force_edgecolor: False
patch.linewidth: 1.0
path.effects: []
path.simplify: True
path.simplify_threshold: 0.1111111111111111
path.sketch: None
path.snap: True
pdf.compression: 6
pdf.fonttype: 3
pdf.inheritcolor: False
pdf.use14corefonts: False
pgf.debug: False
pgf.preamble: []
pgf.rcfonts: True
pgf.texsystem: xelatex
polaraxes.grid: True
ps.distiller.res: 6000
ps.fonttype: 3
ps.papersize: letter
ps.useafm: False
ps.usedistiller: False
savefig.bbox: None
savefig.directory: ~
savefig.dpi: figure
savefig.edgecolor: w
savefig.facecolor: w
savefig.format: png
savefig.frameon: True
savefig.jpeg_quality: 95
savefig.orientation: portrait
savefig.pad_inches: 0.1
savefig.transparent: False
scatter.marker: o
svg.fonttype: path
svg.hashsalt: None
svg.image_inline: True
text.antialiased: True
text.color: k
text.hinting: auto
text.hinting_factor: 8
text.latex.preamble: []
text.latex.preview: False
text.latex.unicode: False
text.usetex: False
timezone: UTC
tk.window_focus: False
toolbar: toolbar2
verbose.fileo: sys.stdout
verbose.level: silent
webagg.address: 127.0.0.1
webagg.open_in_browser: True
webagg.port: 8988
webagg.port_retries: 50
xtick.alignment: center
xtick.bottom: True
xtick.color: k
xtick.direction: out
xtick.labelbottom: True
xtick.labelsize: medium
xtick.labeltop: False
xtick.major.bottom: True
xtick.major.pad: 3.5
xtick.major.size: 3.5
xtick.major.top: True
xtick.major.width: 0.8
xtick.minor.bottom: True
xtick.minor.pad: 3.4
xtick.minor.size: 2.0
xtick.minor.top: True
xtick.minor.visible: False
xtick.minor.width: 0.6
xtick.top: False
ytick.alignment: center_baseline
ytick.color: k
ytick.direction: out
ytick.labelleft: True
ytick.labelright: False
ytick.labelsize: medium
ytick.left: True
ytick.major.left: True
ytick.major.pad: 3.5
ytick.major.right: True
ytick.major.size: 3.5
ytick.major.width: 0.8
ytick.minor.left: True
ytick.minor.pad: 3.4
ytick.minor.right: True
ytick.minor.size: 2.0
ytick.minor.visible: False
ytick.minor.width: 0.6
ytick.right: False
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I found [this comment](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/879#issuecomment-339508107). The issue describes different symptoms but the suggested solution works:

> ```
> pip uninstall shapely
> pip install --no-binary :all: shapely
> ```

Comment: If using anaconda, it is also necessary to install `conda`'s `geos` package, as installing `shapely` like this makes `cartopy` to not find the system's `geos` library

Comment: Went to  upvote this answer, and was told I upvoted this 3 years ago!