# How to deal with segmentation fault when running samples from cartopy documentation?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

On running any of cartopy examples (or any code for plotting purpose using pyplot and cartopy) system returns Segmentation fault

I have already tried the solution listed here: [Cartopy examples produce a Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374356/cartopy-examples-produce-a-segmentation-fault)

```
pip uninstall shapely
pip install --no-binary :all: shapely
```

When I tried running this basic example:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

This is the log:

```
(python:19052): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:40:45.891: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11546:3: '/*' in comment block

(python:19052): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:40:45.891: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11652:2: '/*' in comment block
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this issue: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/738

So I just had to uninstall both cartopy and shapely, and then use:

```
pip install shapely cartopy --no-binary shapely --no-binary cartopy
```